# LoginPage in React with Redirecting

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes, url-routing

I have response from server about auth status current user. Based on this information I'm rendering HomePage or LoginPage. How do I can redirect all unauthorized users to '/login' url and others to homepage. When I`m using history.push('/login') it saves permament in url, because in first rendering auth status is always false

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.scss';
import MainPage from './components/MainPage/MainPage';
import { withRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getAuthStatusThunk } from './redux/authReducer';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Preloader from './components/commons/Preloader/Preloader';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { isCheckingLogin: false }
    this.getAuthStatusThunk = this.props.getAuthStatusThunk.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    getAuthStatusThunk()
  }
  async getAuthStatusThunk() {
    this.setState({ isCheckingLogin: true })
    let res = await (checkIsLoggedIn())
    if (res.isLoggedIn) {
      this.setState({ isCheckingLogin: false })
    }
    else {
      this.props.history.push('/login')
      this.setState({ isCheckingLogin: false })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.isCheckingLogin ? <Preloader isLoading={true} /> : <MainPage />}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

let mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuth: state.authPage.isAuth,
  successStatus: state.authPage.successStatus
})

let FunctionRender = compose(
  withRouter,
  connect(mapStateToProps, { getAuthStatusThunk }))(App)

export default FunctionRender;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep `loading` and `error` value also in the `state`.
Then check if any one of the state value is `set` or `not`.
Based on the state value navigate the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a state `isCheckingLogin` to true while you call the `getAuthStatusThunk`. Here I include a sample snippet for implementing it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = { isCheckingLogin: false }
        this.getAuthStatusThunk = this.getAuthStatusThunk.bind(this)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        getAuthStatusThunk()
    }
    async  getAuthStatusThunk() {
        this.setState({ isCheckingLogin: true })
        let res = await (checkIsLoggedIn())
        if (res.isLoggedIn) {
            this.setState({ isCheckingLogin: false })
        }
        else {
            this.props.history.push('/login')
            this.setState({ isCheckingLogin: false })

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {isCheckingLogin ? <Loader /> : <MainPage />}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

The `Loader` component can be used for showing a spinner or some sort of animation while login status is checked if you want.

Comment: let res = await (checkIsLoggedIn()) 

What is checkIsLoggedIn() doing? Checking status of auth? My full component in header

Comment: checkIsLoggedIn is checking auth status. If it is in header you can sent the status and loading state as props